# Как с помощью split присвоить в несколько хэшей файл построчно?

Tags: perl

Подскажите, как правильно присвоить в 3 хэша 15 строк из txt-файла по 5 key/value для каждого хэша с помощью split?

Пусть txt-файл будет иметь следующую структуру:

```
key1 value1
key2 value2
key3 value3
...
key15 value15
```

Мои действия:

1: Открываю файл на чтение

2: Хочу сделать как-то так `my (%hsh1, %hsh2, %hsh3) = split(' ', $file_for_haches);`, но на этом шаге у меня возникли трудности.

Как сказать перлу, чтобы он в первый хэш положил первые 5 строк, во второй - вторые 5 строк, в третий - третие 5 строк?

Comment: Ни как. сделать split в массив и присваивать хешам срезы (splice) этого массива

Comment: И кстати не совсем ясно, что у вас в переменной $file_for_haches. Вы ничего не сказали о том как вы файл читали. В файле же переводы кареток, вы их уже заменили на пробелы, что бы такой split отработал ?

Comment: да, да, там всё нормально. Я просто пытаюсь сделать по аналогии с присваиванием файла построчно в скаляры, но только по 5 строк для каждого хэша. Дико извиняюсь, если это бред, просто в перле я нуб.

Comment: С левой стороны от равно в любом случае не может быть более 1 хеша. потому что первый же хеш (или массив) поглотит весь присваевымый список. Так что тремя строками. что то вроде `%hsh1=splice(@file, 0, 10);` где @file это то, что дал split

Comment: Ммм, вот оно как. Слишком сложна! Ладно, спасибо. Пойду че-нибудь прочитаю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению присвоить что либо сразу 3 хешам невозможно, первый же хеш слева от оператора `=` поглотит все значения из списка справа.

Если файл еще не прочитан, то можно заполнять хеши по мере чтения файла. Например как нибудь так:

```
open(my $file, "<", "file.txt");
my %hsh1 = map { chomp($_=<$file>); split / / } 1..5;
my %hsh2 = map { chomp($_=<$file>); split / / } 1..5;
my %hsh3 = map { chomp($_=<$file>); split / / } 1..5;
```